# VB6 - Regqueryvalueex returns 2 on 64bit machine

Tags: vb6, registry, 32bit-64bit

the application tries to access the registry key values using advapi.dll regqueryvalueex method which works fine in xp (32-bit) but return 2 on windows 7(64-bit). however regopenkeyex opens the registry keys successfully in both the machines.

tried these below steps already but still couldn't read the registry key values
1. tried running vb 6 ide as admin
2. moved the registry keys to wow64node in regedit

Comment: You seem to be missing your code example.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you are targeting the `advapi.dll` library, which was created for 16-bit Windows. I don't know how you are even getting it to work even in Windows XP, since this is a 16-bit only DLL, which will not load into a Win32 process, unless there is some kind of thunking layer.

As for the return value of "2" for RegOpenKeyEx(), the documentation tells you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is a system error code.
>
> If the lpData buffer is too small to receive the data, the function
>   returns ERROR_MORE_DATA.
>
> If the lpValueName registry value does not exist, the function returns
>   ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Googling "System error code" gives you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The bit you need is:

> ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> ```
> 2 (0x2)
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.
> ```

It is very likely that if you were trying to use `advapi.dll` in your declare statement you would get this error when trying to run the API call. Basically, check your declare statements.

Of course, if you could supply your code, we would know for sure, rather than trying to do psychic debugging.